# Oracle 11g: Convert RAW(8) to table of integer range 0..255

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have variable `lr_temp` and it is `RAW(8)` type. Making on it `RawToHex(lr_temp)` I receive string: `BDAB59967DF11ECC` (8 bytes presented in hex). My problem is to receive integer value for each byte:

```
  dbms_output.put_line(RawToHex(lr_temp));
  FOR i IN 1 .. 8
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(ascii(utl_raw.substr(lr_temp, i, 1)));
  END LOOP;
```

I receive:

```
BDAB59967DF11ECC
66
65
53
57
55
70
49
67
```

But `BD` is `189` not `66`, `AB` is `171` not `65` and so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  dbms_output.put_line(RawToHex(lr_temp));
  FOR i IN 1 .. lcn_data_length
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(utl_raw.cast_to_binary_integer(utl_raw.substr(lr_temp, i, 1)));
  END LOOP;
```

and the output:

```
BDAB59967DF11ECC
189
171
89
150
125
241
30
204
```